# Cannot open ./cookie in Google Colab (YOLOR pretrained models set-up)

Tags: bash, curl, yolo

I am trying to load a pre-trained model from YOLOR's official documentation using the instructions given here (https://github.com/WongKinYiu/yolor)

I am getting an error when I execute the following code:-

```
!cd /content/yolor
!bash /content/yolor/scripts/get_pretrain.sh
```

Contents of pre_train.sh

```
curl -c ./cookie -s -L "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1Tdn3yqpZ79X7R1Ql0zNlNScB1Dv9Fp76" > /dev/null
curl -Lb ./cookie "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=`awk '/download/ {print $NF}' ./cookie`&id=1Tdn3yqpZ79X7R1Ql0zNlNScB1Dv9Fp76" -o yolor_p6.pt
rm ./cookie

curl -c ./cookie -s -L "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1UflcHlN5ERPdhahMivQYCbWWw7d2wY7U" > /dev/null
curl -Lb ./cookie "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=`awk '/download/ {print $NF}' ./cookie`&id=1UflcHlN5ERPdhahMivQYCbWWw7d2wY7U" -o yolor_w6.pt
rm ./cookie
```

output:

```
awk: cannot open ./cookie (No such file or directory)
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  2324    0  2324    0     0  24463      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 24463
rm: cannot remove './cookie': No such file or directory
awk: cannot open ./cookie (No such file or directory)
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  2324    0  2324    0     0  28691      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 28691
rm: cannot remove './cookie': No such file or directory
```

I can't find the hidden cookie file in the google colab folders either.

How do I find the cookie folder?

Comment: curl failed. remove the `>/dev/null` to see the errors

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz The new error after removing that snippet is the HTML code for Google Drive - Virus scan warning given when the file being downloaded is too big. It still can't find the cookie folder either. Is there any way to download it even if google's scan is blocking it? I have downloaded the files onto my computer in case it doesn't work but I have no idea where to place them with respect to the /content/ folder on Colab.

Comment: apart from general problem solving, you might want to talk to the author of the repo: https://github.com/WongKinYiu/yolor/issues